# merging back changes from parent branch

Tags: git

I am starting to use `git` for version control and I have the following scenario.

I have a branch `4000-base`. I branched out of this branch using

```
git checkout 4000-base
git checkout -n 4001-feature-1
```

Now, I have been working on this branch locally. In the meanwhile, the parent branch has been updated. What I would like to do is to take the latest changes from the parent branch, merge it locally to my `4001-feature-1` branch and then push the branch to the server to make it available to everyone.

What is the best way to achieve this in `git`?

Comment: You need to `merge` the parent branch into your branch (and then `push`).

Comment: this is the most basic concept of git, have you tried reading any tutorial at all?

Comment: You might want to go and read the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It starts with the basics and goes into advanced topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git rebase is what you are looking for.

> git-rebase - Reapply commits on top of another base tip

You need to commit your changes to branch `4001-feature-1` branch.
You can update parent.
Then you can use command `git rebase 4000-base` while you are on your `4000-feature-1` branch.
Here you have link with more details on git rebase: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: Also, with regards to `rebase` and `merge`, you probably want to check with your team and find out which one they do (often a team will always do one or the other). [Rebasing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: As long as any commits were not pushed to remote repository I would obtain for `rebase`. Otherwise `merge`. @crashmstr

Comment: The "problem" with git: there are often several *valid* ways to do something. You prefer `rebase`, I prefer `merge` (and would also suggest commiting and pushing changes on the feature branch regularly too). Again, they should talk to their team and find out how the team is working.